# Akka Persistence: Can't read Cassandra config from application.conf

Tags: jar, cassandra, akka, akka-persistence

In my `/src/main/resources/application.conf` file, I am overwriting the values of the Cassandra host like:

```
cassandra-journal {
  contact-points = [${?CASSANDRA_HOST}]
}
```

When I run it with IntelliJ, it is reading them fine. But when I create the jar and run it in a Docker container, the value of `CASSANDRA_HOST` is always 127.0.0.1 and the port is 9042. I have even tried to hardcode different values there, but it seems that it's not reading the `application.conf` file.

(I'm using `sbt assembly` to create the .jar file.)

Comment: Can you give some more context? Like the code in which you read the configuration, the way you launch the program in Intellij vs the way you do it in the jar, etc.

Comment: Could you open the .jar (it is 'just' a zip file) and look what the included `application.conf` looks like? Is it missing, does it have the wrong content (some other `application.conf`?), or perhaps it has a combination of 2 `application.conf` files but one of them does not have a trailing `\n`, invalidating the next one?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you have to add the `DockerPlugin` at your `build.sbt` file.

```
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, JavaServerAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)
```

besides that, opening the jar file is a good idea to check if the `application.conf` file is really there.